# How to safely rollout new npm package version with engine requirement change

Tags: node.js, npm

As node is deprecating old Buffer usages, and unfortunately I'm using it in one of my packages. I'd love to rollout a new version to fix this before too late.

I rolled out a version that drops node < 4 support with patch version number increment, and someone complaints the breakage a few hours later.

As `npm install --save` always includes full semver in `package.json`. Which makes it impossible for deployment machines that runs a different version of node to resolve the package to an earlier version.

If I increase minor version or major version, the users will face the same issue after using `npm install --save`.

I know that the user should use the same version for dev and production, and npm will do the right thing for them. But this is not a perfect world. Is there a way to make this rollout transparent to end users by using some npm features?